# Android studio no marca errores ni permite compilar

Tags: android, studio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Vuelve a abrir proyectos antiguos de android studio que no habia abierto desde que actualize el windows, este fue el primero que abri, le di import project, ya que anteriormente me habia pasado que no se lograba configurar el gradle al darle a open directamente, y se me cargo asi, solamente pintando palabras pero sin reconocer errores ni tener opciones de compilar. Otro proyecto que abri despues se cargo correctamente y funciona, por lo que el error es del proyecto.

Comment: ¿Debe mostrarse un mensaje de error al tener problemas al compilar, revisa el EventLog? Agrega esta información a tu pregunta por favor, saludos.

Comment: No nada, el solo se abre termina de cargar todo y queda así

Comment: Es muy raro que no realice absolutamente nada, o que no muestre nada.Creo que como IDE si no se mostrará algún mensaje no serviría como IDE, te sugiero revises bien de otra forma no hay mucho que hacer si no hay ni un mensaje que indique el problema.

Comment: Pues hize lo del sync files que me dijeron abajo y funciono

Comment: Pues eso es muy raro el Sync Project se realiza automáticamente cuando se compila el proyecto. pero si no hace nada indica que hay un error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hola se que mi respuesta puede sonar obvia pero tengo que preguntarte, ¿Le has dado a la siguiente opción?

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Aclaraciones sobre la pregunta se realizan como comentarios. Si no le permite compilar es porque precisamente al sincronizar el proyecto marca error.

Comment: Bueno ese boton no lo he probado, probe invalidare cache sin efectos y el make project y pareciera no hacer nada el botón

Comment: Bueno esa solución funciono xD

Comment: Me ha pasado en algún proyecto, me alegro que se halla solucionado, saludos!